# When using a ListView in flutter to retrieve a list of json objects from an API. Is it the right way to have an Stateful or Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, mobile

So say I have a simple app with 2 routes. The home route is profile and the second is items. So the idea is that when the user clicks in the item icon the app should move to that route and display all the user's items. The question is should this item Widget be Stateless or Stateful? Take in consideration that I expect the user to pull to refresh this Route and reload the api in the Listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should definitely be a Stateful widget since you are expecting data from an API. A stateless widget can't change, you should only use a Stateless widget if the data on the page is static.

Comment: But can I just call the API and render in a ListView the results before rendering the Stateless Widget. Taking in consideration that the ListView will not change unless the user pull to refresh which is equivalent to re-render the ListView.

Comment: Where do you place to call the API? Because to my knowledge, the init state function is only available in a stateful widget.

Comment: Got me there. I can manually create bools to manage this but for that is just better to go with Stateful.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have an accepted answer which is correct, but wanted to add that generally if you use a state management solution like Provider, Bloc, GetX etc...they all provide widgets that will refresh a `ListView` without needing to be inside a stateful widget.

That will be a cleaner and more scalable solution than calling `setState` from within a stateful widget.

Comment: You know this is interesting. I know Bloc is the best way to go forward but I also heard is way more complicated. Is just I didnt understand why use stateful when literally I could have used stateless and once the user pull to refresh re-draw the widget. But as Becca explained I need a way to call the API, right?

Comment: You can accomplish this with any state management solution. In my opinion, GetX is the easiest and has the least amount of boilerplate code. But don't get hung up on which one is "the best". But I do strongly recommend picking one to start and learning it. Your code that calls the API should live in an external state management class that notifies and updates the UI.

Answer (score -1):

Its definitely an stateful widget because stateless widget can't change their  state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: because stateless widget is use when we need something static on our page for example terms and condition page.